# how to count multiple rows and return the result in pl/sql oracle packages

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

i have a table that has multiple records, however some records are similar from the following table

Table 1

```
Code         P1       P2         P3
 W           5        10         20
 S           5        10         20
 W           6        20         35
```

if i pass P1 , P2 , P3 as parameters following

```
select *
from table 1
where P1=5 and P2=10 and P3=20
```

it will return the result W and S,but only the W that matches to the paramteres.
How do i go about creating a package that will count all the multiple records and return the codes that are similar? I am not familiar with oracle

Comment: it is not quite clear, what are you trying to achieve...  why 'only W matches' ? clarify your question  and  give an example of desired output.

Comment: no S matches aswell, i mentioned that W and S should be returned because it has matching parameters, but if you notice theres 2 W's so only the corresponding W will get returned

Comment: so you want to return a similar result as the query you provided, say this one :   `select code
from table1
where P1=5 and P2=10 and P3=20`  - only a result should come  from a function (inside a package) ?

Comment: yes, thats what im trying to do

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with [pipelined](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm) functions.

**declare package and types**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mytestpackage AS

    TYPE my_record is RECORD(
           code       varchar2
    );

    TYPE my_table IS TABLE OF my_record;

function  get_results(par1 number,par2 number,par3 number)  RETURN my_table PIPELINED;

end mytestpackage;
```

**package body**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY as 

    function  get_results(par1 number,par2 number,par3 number)  RETURN my_table PIPELINED is 
        my_rec   my_record:=null;
        cursor myCursor(myp1 number,myp2 number,myp3 number) is
        select code from table1 where P1=myp1 and P2=myp2 and P3=myp3
        ;

        begin 

        --loop through outputs 

         FOR item IN myCursor(par1,par2,par3)  LOOP
          my_rec:=null; 
          select item.code into my_rec from dual;
          PIPE ROW(my_rec);
         end loop;
        return;
        end; 
end mytestpackage;
```

**and finally use it**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(mytestpackage.get_results(5,10,20));
```